# Last two letters of a user inputted string using substring (Java)

Tags: java, string, substr

I'm writing a program that generates star wars names. The user inputs their first, last, mother's maiden name, birth city, and first car and the program gives a star wars name. I need  the last two characters* of the user inputted last name. I know I can use `substring`, but I cannot get anything to work. The best I have is:

```
lastname.substring(lastname.length() -2)
```

which gives the first two letters of the last name, and not the last. Also, I cannot use `lastname.substr(-2)` because `substr` for some reason won't work (not sure why, this would be much easier).

Thanks for any help.

*EDIT: I hope I didn't confuse anyone, I need the last two characters of the last name.

Actually I see my problem now: my original last name variable is

```
String lastname = console.nextLine().substring(0,2).trim().toUpperCase();
```

which keeps the first two letters, so the reason I was getting the first two letters was because of this. I understand now. Is there a way to get the last two letters from this same variable?

Comment: Look into the overloaded `substring` method.

Comment: Your code produces the last two, not the first two, characters ([demo](http://ideone.com/LDq4Z2)).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis String is final and cannot be overloaded.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 I think you might be confused between overloading and overriding. Overloading is when you have the same method name, but different parameter lists. `String` has two `substring` methods.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight For some reason I'm getting the first two characters, and not the last, although I see in your demo that you get the last two. I don't understand why the same code is give two different outputs??

Comment: Check the second part of my answer for the answer to your updated question. I didn't understand you at first.

Comment: Try to write and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for your problem with `lastname.substring(lastname.length() -2)`. The substring and length methods in `java.lang.String` are **very** reliable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, I am not confusing them. The String class is final and therefore no methods can be either overloaded or overridden. Besides the point that it was unneccessary for the purposes of the question. Although it would be nice to be able to override the method to suppurt negative input and interpret it as 'length - n'.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 Now you are obviously confusing them. Marking a class as `final` means it cannot be extended. Since there can be no sub class, there can be no overriden methods. [Overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) has absolutely nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 As the link I posted states, `The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists (there are some qualifications to this that will be discussed in the lesson titled "Interfaces and Inheritance").`

Comment: @LINEMAN78 That's exactly what `String` does with [`String#substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) and [`String#substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)). Same name, different parameter list. Those methods are overloading eachother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if the name was `Michael`, you just want `Micha`?

Try:

```
String trimmedLastName = lastName.substring(0, lastName.length() - 2);
```

For example:

```
String lastName = "Michael";
String trimmedLastName = lastName.substring(0, lastName.length() - 2);
System.out.println(trimmedLastName); // prints Micha
```

The reason mine works and yours doesn't is because the first parameter of [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) is where to *start*. So I start from the first letter, and end on the second last letter (not inclusive).

What yours does is start on the second last letter, and continue on until the end of the string.

---

However, if you wanted just `el` from `Michael`, you could do this:

```
String lastName = "Michael";
String trimmedLastName = lastName.substring(lastName.length() - 2);
System.out.println(trimmedLastName); // prints el
```

Comment: Yes your right, this does work. I caught my original error--thx for the help!

Comment: @user125347 Please accept my answer then, seeing as it worked for you (click the checkmark to the left of the answer).

Comment: @user125347 If you are planning to append something to the end of the trimmed name it would be more efficient to use 'StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(lastName); sb.setLength(lastName.length()-2);' and keep it as a StringBuilder. For more info on why this is more efficient read about the String Pool. While the compiler (1.6+) tries to help you with this it isn't smart enough to get you all the way there especially in a loop. You seem to be doing this once in response to a user action so you won't notice any performance difference, but just in case you were to apply to a large database.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 I agree with that, however adding stuff like that into the answer will just confuse the questioner, and it won't even help them specifically because it won't affect their performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
lastname.substring(lastname.length() -3,lastname.length() -1);
```

Comment: Pls share exception traces. also make sure you have handled NPE

Comment: I think the issue occurred due to my original lastname variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the different ways, here:

```
StringBuffer myString = new StringBuffer(inputString);
myString.revert();

StringBuffer userInput = new StringBuffer(myString.subString(2));

String result = userInput.revert();
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

`lastname.substring(lastname.length() - 2)` should return the last 2 letters.

`lastname.substring(0, 2)` returns the first two.

`substring(index)` is includive

`substring(index1, index2)` is inclusive, exclusive respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Because String is immutable so when you call subString it doesn't change the value of lastname.

I think you should do:
String genName = lastname.subString(lastname.lengh()-2);