# Adding birth year to username

Tags: java

I am new here and I could use some help with a small problem.  I looked through old questions, but none seemed along the same lines as mine. I am creating a program for a user to register their info (name, birth year, and password).  When a user enters a name that is not available, I want to take the last two digits of their birth year, or the only digits (ex:  if they enter 1985 or just 85, I want the 85 in both cases) and I want to put these two digits on the end of the user name, as an option for a different name that isn't taken.  (example:  The name Bruce is already taken, Try Bruce85.)  I tried a simple string in a different program which took the number of the location where a letter is, but I need to reverse that, and find a number (85)  from the last two numbers.  1985 = 0 1 2 3, so I want to find what number falls under 2 and 3, no matter what number is entered (since I don't know what number is entered before hand).

This is what I tried using in string form.  I tried numbers later with no luck:

```
String myWord = "Bruce";
int location = myWord.indexOf("c");
System.out.println(location);
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason for using birth year as String?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last two letters of a user inputted string using substring (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187613/last-two-letters-of-a-user-inputted-string-using-substring-java)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use

```
 char[] ye = year.toCharArray();
```

this returns splited year, add ye[2] and ye[3] to name.

```
String myWord = "Bruce";
int location = myWord.indexOf("c");
System.out.println(location);

String year = "1952";
char[] ye = year.toCharArray();
myWord = myWord+ ye[2] + ye[3] ;

System.out.println(myWord);
```

You may use other values also. Be aware od Null pointer exception.

For best practices dont use char array. Instead of that use String functions like

```
String myWord1 = myWord+ ye[2] + ye[3] ;
System.out.println(myWord1);

String[] ary = year.split(""); // Use Regex here 
String myWord2 = myWord + ary[2] + ary[3] ;
System.out.println(myWord2);

String myWord3= myWord + year.substring(1, 3);
System.out.println(myWord3);
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir.  Your answer is what led me to be able to finish this.  It took about half an hour, but I got it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `substring` api to get last two digit of your birthDate like below:

```
String birthDate = "1985";
System.out.println(birthDate.substring(birthDate.length() - 2));
```